# Incorrect timezone ID inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, centos, timezone

I have created a docker image from the base Centos7 image and while running the container from it, the time and timezone were not in sync with my host. To give the container the same timezone as that of the host. I mounted /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime from the host to the container using the '-v' argument while running the container. 
After running the container with this, this is what i get inside the container and host:

**For docker container running timedatectl:**

```
[root@d7a24c723f6a /]# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2017-08-01 10:28:30 IST
  Universal time: Tue 2017-08-01 04:58:30 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: UTC (IST, +0530)
     NTP enabled: n/a
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

**For host running timedatectl:**

```
[root@indiadev72 ~]# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2017-08-01 10:27:29 IST
  Universal time: Tue 2017-08-01 04:57:29 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2017-08-01 04:57:29
       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

I am not sure why my docker container is not able to take the timezone of the host.

***EDIT***:
Also while running some of my test cases, i am able to see that the application is reading timezoneid as 'GMT+530' instead of Asia/Kolkata. While GMT+530 is indeed Asia/Kolkata but due the timezone ID mismatch inside the container my test cases are failing.
Maybe its just the timezoneID issue and the container is picking up the correct time. Can someone please help here?

Comment: Please format the output as code so it doesn't get merged into a single line

Comment: Does [this post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes) help?  Also, is the `tzdata` package installed in your docker image?

Comment: I have already done that and yes the image has tzdata package installed. ?The issue seems to be just the timezoneID, my application expects timezoneID to be Asia/Kolkata but its reading 'GMT+530'. They are factually same but the ID is different. Can you check in your docker image by running timedatectl?